# How to access config.xml of James from the POP3Server class?

Tags: java, settings, inversion-of-control, pop3, james

I am changing some parts of the James `POP3Server` class and inject it afterwards via IoC.
I need to configure some parts I like to use in my modifications, and I thought it would be handy if I could use the `config.xml` to store my settings.

`POP3Server.class` <-> `config.xml` (direct access possible?)

Is there a easy way of accessing this XML or do I have to access it somewhere deeper inside James?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code for `org.apache.james.pop3server.POP3Server` and find `public void configure(final Configuration configuration)`: this handles configuration of the server with the XML from `config.xml`. For example, if you modify the POP3Server XML configuration block in the `james-config` file to look like this:

```
<pop3server enabled="true">
      <port>110</port>
      <handler>
         <helloName autodetect="true">myMailServer</helloName>
         <connectiontimeout>120000</connectiontimeout>
      </handler>
      <myconfigvariable>12</myconfigvariable>
   </pop3server>
```

you'll be able to add a line in `configure` like this:

```
int myconfig = configuration.getChild("myconfigvariable").getValueAsInteger(25);
```

The `25` here is the default in the case where the config variable is missing. Let me know if that does what you want.